# How to change numbers around in a list in python

Tags: python, list, switching

I have a list [50,30,20,10,40] and I am trying to exchange the variables.
So what I want to do is if the first number is greater than the next, we have have to flip them. 
So this should return [30,20,10,40,50]

The code I have so far is given the l as the list

```
a=''
b=''
c=''
for i in range(len(l)):
    if (l[i+1]<l[i]):
        a=l[i]
        b=l[i+1]
        c=a
        a=b
        b=c
        print [a,b,c]
    else:
        print listOrig
```

Comment: Are you trying to sort it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python makes swapping easy:

```
for i in range(len(l)-1):
    if (l[i+1] < l[i]):
        l[i+1], l[i] = l[i], l[i+1]
```

Notes:

- for loop goes up to range(len(i) - 1), otherwise your index will be out of range
- Avoid using single letter variable such as `l`. In my opinion, loop variable `i` is OK